# Como aceitar uma lista como input?

Tags: python-3.x

Esse é um exercício de um curso da USP. Vou postar o enunciado e o código para que a dúvida fique clara.

*Escreva a função remove_repetidos que recebe como parâmetro uma lista com números inteiros, verifica se tal lista possui elementos repetidos e os remove. A função deve devolver uma lista correspondente à primeira lista, sem elementos repetidos. A lista devolvida deve estar ordenada.*

**Meu código:**

```
def remove_repetidos(x):
    c = 0

    x.sort()

    while c < len(x)-1:
        if x[c] == x[c+1]:
            del x[c]
        else:
            c = c+1
    return x


x = input("Digite sua lista:")

lista = remove_repetidos(x)

print (lista)
```

---

Sei que o código não está otimizado.
Mas a dúvida é, como adaptar a função para que ela receba diversas listas como input?

Por exemplo,o usuário quer rodar o código e digitar uma lista qualquer e ter como retorno uma lista com os números repetidos removidos?

Abs,

Answer (score 2):

Quando você pega dados via `input( )` o Python presume ser uma `string`. Para transformar em "lista", na verdade `array`, circunde a função `input( )` com `eval( )`, já colocados os colchetes, e digite os valores separados por vírgula:

```
x = eval('[' + input("Digite sua lista: ") + ']')
```

Exemplo:

```
>>> Digite sua lista: 4, 4, 8, 6, 7, 9, 9
>>> [4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Ao mesmo tempo você vai estar a margem de todos os possíveis erros caso o usuário digite um valor indevido, como uma `string` em um dos índices, por exemplo `[3, 4, 'a', 3]`, por conta da função `sort( )`.

Comment: é possível fazer isso parar ler sem que os números estejam separados por vírgulas? por exemplo 12345